# How do i find the other two strongholds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So i found the first stronghold on minecraft. I found the first stronghold using eye of ender. I went through the stronghold and took the contents of the chest. I also fixed the portal to the end went to the end and then went back to spawn. How can i find the other 2 strongholds using the eye of ender?

Comment: You can't. The eye of ender will always link to the same stronghold (which is whichever one you're nearest when you throw your first EOE).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to find another one?

Comment: If you get really, really lucky while digging. Or alternatively, there are programs that search chunks for various things (so you could search for bookcases, and strongholds are the only places they occur naturally, so you could find strongholds that way. That is cheating though, so the only way to find more strongholds is to mine for ages in a 500 block radius around the spawnpoint).

Comment: @imulsion you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! Im new to this.. is there a way to let the website know that you're awesome and a great help?

Comment: I'll post as an answer, then you can upvote and accept it :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The eye of ender locks on to whatever stronghold you're nearest to when you throw your first one. Therefore, the only way to find multiple strongholds is to get lucky while mining or use a chunk search program. Search for bookcases, and since stronghold libraries are the only places where bookcases naturally occur, this will allow you to locate all three strongholds. This is cheating though, so mining for ages is the only legitimate way to find all of them.

Comment: I cant upvote sorry it requires reputation

Comment: @user62749 I forgot >.< don't worry about it, thanks for accepting :)

Comment: Glad to do so (: is there anyother way? Like asking easy question?

Comment: @user62749 Please avoid "boosting" reputation. Let a good answer be a reward of itself - here's my +1, I didn't know about Eyes locking to a single Stronghold.

Comment: Something else, I've heard rumors that Strongholds give off special ambiance sound effects. I can't find anything on the wiki that supports this though.

Comment: was this a recent change? or was it always like this? cuz in the past, i have thrown ender pearls, followed them, and then they change direction. (And no i wasnt at the stronghold)

Comment: @gamewin1 this was fairly recent (1.6.4 and above) obviously your situation could mean you running around in circles, never finding the stronghold

Comment: At least in 1.8.1 eyes are not locking on one stronghold. I walked far enough from the first stronghold and eyes started to show me a way to the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to the 0,0 coords and heading in the oposite way as the stronghold you already found.The eyes of ender will take you to the nearest stronghold.The third one should be a little more tricky since you will have to go away from two strongholds so be sure to go away from BOTH strongholds you already know.

Answer (score 1):

The 3 central strongholds are quite precisely laid out 120 degrees from each other on rays from [0,0], within the allowed distance (1,408-2,688 blocks of the world origin).

[image]

The lighter-blue areas on the green "rays" are the two areas where the two remaining strongholds can be found.

So using a little trigonometry, arithmetics, or even just the in-game compass, you'll be able to determine the fairly narrow "strips" of land where they can possibly be quite accurately. Using eyes of ender to triangulate the exact position at that stage is fairly easy.

Comment: The accepted answer claims you won't be able to find the other two with the eyes of ender, as they'll always point to the same stronghold.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Eyes of ender always point to the **nearest** stronghold. So using this method you'll find yourself in general vicinity of a different stronghold than the one you had found first, and the eyes of ender will now point to the new stronghold. There's absolutely nothing special about the first thrown eye, it doesn't "lock" the consecutive ones to anything.

Comment: ...additionally, bookcases also generate in villages. Maybe the accepted answer was valid some long time in the past, it definitely isn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading and using AMIDST, as it finds all three strongholds along with villages, witch huts, temples, slime chunks, your spawnpoint and nether fortresses. I always use it.